# NestJS - send Body to Response

Tags: nestjs

```
@Post('signin')
  async signIn(@Body() account) {
    return this.appService.signIn(account);
  }

******************************
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "use cache",
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJ1c2VyMkB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTYxMDY3NjkyNSwiZXhwIjoxNjEwNzEyOTI1fQ.Tx3a0brtWYD7GQUKYQAq_48biIZCFpqEQsds2-BrINc"
}

-----------------------------------

@Post('signin')
  async signIn(@Body() account, @Res() res: Response) {
    res.send({
      result: this.appService.signIn(account)
    })
  }

******************************

{
    "result": {}
}
```

I'm trying to send the result as Response.

But result is `{} //undefined` if i using `res.json()` or `res.send()`

Cookie-parser, `app.use(cookieParser())` is already done.

1. How do i send Body using Response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `this.appService.login()` is an `async` call, you need to `await` the response before using `res.send()`. Something like this should do

```js
@Post('signin')
  async signIn(@Body() account, @Res() res: Response) {
    const result = await this.appService.signIn(account);
    res.send({
      result
    });
  }
```

Is there any reason you want to inject the `@Res()` instead of letting Nest handle it?

Comment: I'd like to set cookie using ```@Res()```. 
Is there any solution setting cookie without using Res()?

Comment: If you want to inject res but still have nest handle the response you can do `@Res{ passthrough: true })` [as described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies) or you could use a package like [nest-cookies](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-cookies) (disclaimer: I'm the author of that package)

Comment: It doesn't work i expected. But thanks for your answer.
I think it looks better setting cookies at client-side.